# Garbled text while reading from external process in Java

Tags: java, ls, processbuilder

I am launching the SSH utility bundled with Cygwin, using ProcessBuilder Class in Java. Everything works fine. I connect to a linux server over SSH, can run commands and read the output.

However, whenever the output is returned, it only happens after login on the server and running commands e.g directory listing `ls`, returns something like this:

```
InputStream: root@myserver:/scripts/common# ls 
InputStream: [00m[00mA1-4.yaml[00m                            [01;32mscip-1.2.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.qso[00m
InputStream: [00madditional_files.txt[00m                 [01;32mscip-1.2.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx[00m
```

As far as I have figured out, it is only happening with file listing command. For example when I am running other commands like time, etc it shows normal output.

Can you suggest what it is that is appending these random characters to the filename?

I have even tried to use UTF8 encoding but nothing changes. When I directly login using the command line, I do not see those results. However, the cmdline shows file names in colored values. Is it that there is some additional information added which is not ASCII?

Comment: OK, i just realized it was indeed the case. There are short color code values which print into non-ascii characters are added and as such raw output looks fine in cmdline, it shows different in retrieved text. With calling this: ls --color=none it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Guess someone should delete this question. Thanks

Comment: You should actually create an answer to your question, because it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command `ls --color=none`  solves this problem.

This happens because by default ls command returns file names which have different color code values appended to them. [This link gives more information](http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html).

Following picture describes the difference between `ls` and `ls --color=none`:

[image]